# Ajax call results in typeparserroroccured, with syntaxError: unexpected token

Tags: php, jquery, json

I'm attempting to do an AJAX call, and I am forming an associative array :
when I list dataType: as JSON I receive the **syntax Error: unexpected token**, when I send with data-type HTML it works fine, however I cannot access the `data.success` property of the return array, unless I send datatype JSON.

```
var participant_information = 
{"Username":participant_name,"relation":participant_relation,"action":action};


 $.ajax({
      url: '<?php echo base_url();?>transaction/manage_participant/',
      async: false,
      type: 'POST',
      data: {participant_information : participant_information},
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data) {

      if(data.success) { }


      }
```

### PHP

```
$status['success'] = 'success';

    echo json_encode($status);
```

Comment: Look at the network tab of your browser's dev tools and see what the actual response is. Or leave the dataType unspecified and just do `console.log(data)`

Comment: I suspect your script is printing something before it calls `json_encode()`.

Comment: `console.log(data);` inside the success call returns `{"success":"success"}` as expected.

Comment: whats error you getting in php/ajax

Comment: @nitishKumar `typeparserroroccured, with syntaxError: unexpected token`

Comment: after getting response

Comment: I didn't know you could use php echo in a javascript...

Comment: so If I do `ob_clean();` then `exit();` following my echo `json_encode($status);` line, I receive no errors. My question is what am i looking for in my code echo statements?

Comment: One thing to look for would be whitespace outside of php tags. Maybe  a line or a space at the beginning of the file.